# How to perform T-Product of two Tensors using einsum notation?

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensor, einsum

Tensor Product :

I want to take T-Product of two Tensors

```
$\matcal{A}, \matcal{B} \in C^{n \times n \times n}$
```

So, as you all know, T-Product is defined as,

```
$C = Fold(Batch_Circulant(\matcal{A} * Unfold(\matcal{B}))$
```

I am trying to solve this using Einstein notation.

In Tensorflow, I'm trying to use `tf.einsum()` for this.

Somebody please help.

I tried,

`tf.einsum('ijk,klm->ijl', A, B)`

And

`tf.einsum('ijk,klm->ijl', tf.roll(A, 1, axis=0), B)`